# How to pass an array containing all the argument to a function requesting multiple arguments in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

The idea is to pass an array `args[]` having `[<int>, <String>, <int>]`

to a function accepting multiple arguments like:

`myFunc (int arg1, String arg2, int arg2 ):void`

Such that the function call :

`myFunc(args[]);` can be realized  without altering the original function call.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Function.apply()`.

In your case

```
myFunc.apply(null,args);
```

Your args[] should contain same order of your myFunc args list match with your datatype.

So that you can't alter you original function.

Performance wise `apply()` is not so good. Other situation you can use `call()`.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html#apply()

Comment: Thank you that worked, as I wanted it too. If you are aware of the internals can you please share why will myFunc.call() have a performance hit when compared to normal function call ? Is it due to Run time data type resolution

Answer (score 0):

strictly speaking, polymorphism is not supported, so if your function has this signature :

```
myFunc (arg1:int, arg2:String, arg3:int):void
```

any call of `myFunc(array);` will throw a compile error.
There are two ways of achieving what I think you want : either you define your first arg as `:*` or you use the special AS3 `...rest`

1. first solution, the function is defined as such:

   ```
   myFunc (arg1:*, arg2:String = null, arg3:int = null):void{
     if(arg1 is Array){
       var array:Array = arg1 as Array;
       arg1 = array[0] as int;
       arg2 = array[1] as String;
       arg3 = array[2] as int;
     }
     //here you would have to verify your args for coherence
     ...//your code here
   }
   ```
2. second solution (I like it better, but it's mainly a 'taste' thing) :

   ```
   myFunc (...rest):void{
     var array:Array = rest[0] as Array,
         arg1:int = rest[0] as int,
         arg2:String = rest[1] as String,
         arg3:int = rest[2] as int,
     if(array is Array){
       arg1 = array[0] as int;
       arg2 = array[1] as String;
       arg3 = array[2] as int;
     }
     //here you would have to verify your args for coherence
     ...//your code here
   }
   ```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am not allowed to change the function definition or signature and hence @Raja Jaganathan 's answer looks more appropriate.

Comment: yes @Raja Jaganathan's answer should work beautifully in this case.

Answer (score -2):

myFunc (args[0], args[1], args[2]);

Comment: breaks the basic premise of the question

Comment: @catholicon - Don't you have anything better to do? Such as offering a solution! You will find that the premise of the question is impossible. Something must change.

Comment: For the answer check out the answer from Raja. Why should I add another copy of the correct answer. I just up-voted it!!